# In R is there a way to replace a specific text in several lines of code?

Tags: r, replace

I would like to run the same code but change the name of the data frame each time so I can run the same analysis for several different datasets I have. Is there a more efficient way to alter my code for a instance with a simple replace function or would I have to do it manually each time?

This is what my code looks like:

````
    ```{r}
jd_df_wthr_corr <- subset(jd_df_wthr_lag, year < 2016) 
```

##Correlation of temperature (avg)

```{r}
jd_df_wthr_corr %>%
  ggplot(aes(logn, mean_temp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE)

cor.test(jd_df_wthr_corr$logn, jd_df_wthr_corr$mean_temp)
```


### with a 1 week lag

```{r}
jd_df_wthr_corr %>%
  ggplot(aes(lag_1week, mean_temp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE)

cor.test(jd_df_wthr_corr$lag_1week, jd_df_wthr_corr$mean_temp, use = "complete")
```
````

This goes on for about 2500 lines. I want to run the same code but replace every instance of "jd" with "jz" or every instance of "jd_df_wthr_corr" with "jz_df_wthr_corr". I notice that when I double click on a specific text it highlights that same text everywhere it appears on the code, which makes me think there should be a way to replace it everywhere.

Comment: You have identified one of the main reasons that R allows people to define functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
results <- sapply(c(frame1, frame2), function(df) { return(run.analysis(df)) }, simplify=TRUE)
```

If it doesn't work, leave a comment, but I hope that helps.

Comment: I've added some sample code to my original question. How would I incorporate your suggested code to get the result I'm looking for?